# C# - how do I get the code to work in different classes?

Tags: c#, class, monogame, stress

I'm making a new game (in Visual Studio, using MonoGame template), and I figured that classes make everything tidier and easier to find/work with - my one problem is that I have no idea how to link one class to another.

Lemme go more into depth - I'm just working with moving the player in the direction corresponding to WASD keys. I've got code that works fine when in the normal Game1 class, but I want it to be in a class specifically for keyboard input.

Note - I haven't touched any of the "using" stuff at the top of the classes.

here's my code:

*Keyboard Input class:*

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace rpg_game
{
   internal class KeyboardInput
   {
      public int player_X;
      public int player_Y;

      KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

      public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
      {
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) { player_Y -=1; }
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) { player_X -= 1; }
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) { player_Y += 1; }
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) { player_X += 1; }
      }
   }
}
```

just to clarify, if theres /* ... */ within the classes, it just means that I've not added or taken anything from them - those classes are untouched :)

*Game1 class:*

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace rpg_game
{
   public class Game1 : Game
   {
      private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
      private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
      
      private Texture2D player;

      private int player_X = 100;
      private int player_Y = 38;

      KeyboardInput input = new KeyboardInput();

      public Game1() { /* ... */ }

      protected override void Initialize() { /* ... */ }

      protected override void LoadContent()
      {
         player = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");
      }

      protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
      {
         input.player_X = player_X;
         input.player_Y = player_Y;

         input.Update(gameTime);
      }

      protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
      {
         GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
         
         _spriteBatch.Begin();
         _spriteBatch.Draw(player, new Rectangle(player_X, player_Y, 25, 25), Color.White);
         _spriteBatch.End();

         base.Draw(gameTime);
      }
   }
}
```

I've provided pretty much everything in each class, but in the Game1 class, the problem (I think), is in the Update.

My question, in short, is how can I get it so that the keyboard input is in another class, yet works the same way as when it was all in the Game1 class?

With it now in a different place, the player doesn't move when I run the code.
What do I need to do in order to use classes and still get the code to do what it's supposed to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your keyboard class, you have defined a new variable of `player_X` and `player_Y`.

Those are different from the `player_X` and `player_Y` you used in `Game1`, so it doesn't make a connection between them.

Adding a parameter to the `KeyboardInput.Update()` could work, but those will only update if you use ref, like this:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, ref int Player_Y, ref int Player_X)
```

Additionally, you can also update variables if you bring a class as a parameter, you could still use `ref` as an easy way out, but I think that'll be messy with many `ref` parameters.

I think you're on the right path to use classes, but I'll also recommend to make a `Player` class as well. and place the `player_X` and `player_Y` there.
From there, you either add the `Player` class to the parameter of `KeyboardInput.Update()`, or you could place the `Update()` code in the Player class instead. (the latter would be my preference)

Example of a Player class:

```
namespace rpg_game
{
   public class Player
   {
      public int X;
      public int Y;

      private Texture2D playerSprite;

      KeyboardState keyboardState = null; //can also work fine with just "KeyboardState keyboardState;", but I prefer defining them with '= null'
      
      public void Load(Texture2D sprite)
      {
          player.playerSprite = sprite;
      }

      public void Update()
      {
         keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState()
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) { Y -=1; }
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) { X -= 1; }
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) { Y += 1; }
         if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) { X += 1; }
      }
      
      //While at it, you could also add a draw Method, and call the player.Draw in the Game1.cs
      public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
      {
         spriteBatch.Draw(playerSprite, new Rectangle(X, Y, 25, 25), Color.White);
      }
   }
}
```

Then, in the Game1.cs, you could define the Player class there:

```
//right underneath the KeyboardInput input = new KeyboardInput(); You'll need to remove the player_X, player_Y and Texture2D variables afterwards
Player player = new Player() {playerSprite = player, X = 100, Y = 38}

//In the LoadContent(), underneath the 'player = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");'
player.load(player); //might want to rename the Texture2D 'player' to something else to work.

//In the Update()
player.Update(); //gameTime parameter is only necessary if you're going to use it.

//In the Draw(), should still be between the spritebatch.Begin and spritebatch.End
player.Draw(_spriteBatch); //replaces the _spriteBatch.Draw(player /*...*/ );
```

(You'll need to remove the X and Y variables in the Game1 class, as those will no longer be relevant)

If you still wish to use the KeyboardInput.Update instead of the Player.Update, then you could remove the `Player.Update()` method, and add the parameter to KeyboardInput.Update (The `player_x`/`player_Y` needs to be changed as well):

```
  public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Player player)
  {
     if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) { player.Y -=1; }
     if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) { player.X -= 1; }
     if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) { player.Y += 1; }
     if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) { player.X += 1; }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! 
When I run it, it stops and says that the Texture2D called playerSprite - that we used to draw in the Player class - can't be null. I didn't know if you'd forgotten some code or if mine just wan't working..
I tried writing in the LoadContent of the Game1 class: `player.playerSprite = Content.Load<Texture2D>( /*...*/)` , which draws my player on the screen - though I had to change the playerSprite from private to public.
But I can't move him... I made a Player class and put the update code in it, so I'm not sure why he can't move - could you please help? :)

Comment: Just a follow-up to my first comment - I got him to move now! In the Player class, I changed the KeyboardState line to `KeyboardState keyboardState` , and then, lower down, defined it inside the Update() , before the WASD code -  `keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState()` . My player moves perfectly - thank you!! :) No doubt I'll hit another issue before long... :D

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! I noticed I forgot to finish a sentence ("You'll need to remove the ..."), in which case I probably meant the variables you defined in the game1 class: `player` (Texture2D), `X` and `Y`, I also forgot that the playerSprite needs to be defined before using, which can be done through a Load() method. I'll update my answer with your response.

Comment: ah okay! I think I did that :) I'm having problems with getting the camera to follow the player round, and stopping at the end of the background image... Any advice? :)